# CSV | Text stored as elements of a list

Tags: python, csv

I am creating a csv file which gathers several articles scraped from a website. The articles are obtained by scraping the text from URLs contained in another file. 
I would like to make the CSV file as a list in which each article corresponds to an element of the list.

The code that I used now is this:

```
import csv
import requests
from bf4 import BeautifulSoup


with open('Training_news.csv', newline='') as file:
    reader= csv.reader (file, delimiter=' ')
    for row in reader:
        for url in row:
            r=requests.get(url)
            r.encoding = "ISO-8859-1"
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
            text = soup.find_all(("p",{"class": "story-body-text story-content"}))
with open('Training_News_5.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    spamwriter.writerow(text)
```

However, the CSV file created gives me this:

```
 <p>Advertisement</p>, <p class="byline-dateline"><span class="byline" itemprop.......
 <p class="feedback-message">We’re interested in your feedback on this page. <strong>Tell us what you think.</strong></p>, <p class="user-action"><a href="http://www.nytimes.com/">Go to Home Page »</a></p>
```

The articles stored are only three out of 50 and they do not allow me to select each article individually.

Comment: Why are you using `|` as the quote character and wrapping `all_text` in a single-element list?

Comment: I just applied the example on how to use csv.reader from the library website https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: The wrapping is because it was the only way I managed to make the text readable. Otherwise I would have got something like this as output: t i t l e = " T i m e s  a r t i c  l e . " >

Comment: Did you think at all about what your actual needs would be while typing it in, though? You may note that the example in the docs is: 1. using non-standard values to demonstrate their use (do you actually want to quote with a *pipe*?!); and 2. writing a list of items into each row. Here you write one single item, which for some reason is a stringified list. I would suggest you take a more thoughtful approach to this, rather than just guessing and hoping for the best. Likely what you want is for the list that results from `soup.findall` to be written to your file one column per item...?

Comment: Actually it would be useful to clarify that: what output *are* you expecting? Don't you just want `spamwriter.writerow(text) `?

Comment: Yes, I do want that. But when I just include spamwriter.writerow(text) the file contains only the body of the first URL.

Comment: The idea is to have a single column in the CSV file, in which each item corresponds to the body of an article

Comment: You reopen it in (over)`w`rite mode every time, which truncates previous content - if that's not what you want, change *that*. Either open the file only once, or use e.g. `a`ppend mode.

Comment: I tried with the append mode but when I try to print a value of the the file I don't get back the text scraped.

Comment: Please give a [mcve] of that, then.

Comment: I wrote it as an answer to the question, hope it is fine

Comment: No, of course that isn't fine, it's not an answer. [Edit] the question.

Comment: Thanks for the advice

Comment: Are you sure that the delimiter is space (`delimiter=' '`)?
Could you provide a snippet of your input csv file, please?